# How do I see code that I have just reviewed in TFS in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

How do I see code that I have just reviewed in TFS in Visual Studio?

Another developer has made code changes to the project and submitted a code review.  I reviewed the code and made the automated"Looks Good" response.

I have learned that he did not complete the process to check the code in.  How do I go about looking at his changes?  He says that it is on his local computer but, then again, I saw the code changes.  Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You could find this in My Work-- Code Reviews

[image]

There is an ID in front of the code reviews, you could also use Query to filter and find the corresponding code review.

For detail process, you could also take a look at this tutorial-- [Get your code reviewed with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/get-code-reviewed-vs?view=azure-devops)